# How can Excel VBA range variables be tested for references to entire columns..?

Tags: excel, vba

What ways are there to test an Excel VBA range variable for references to entire columns?

I'm using Excel 2007 VBA, iterating through Range variables with For-Each loops. The ranges are passed into the function as parameters. References to individual cells, ranges of cells, and entire rows are fine.

For instance, these are okiedokie:

```
Range("A1")     'One cell
Range("A1:D4")  'Range of cells.
Range("10:20")  'Entire rows 10 through 20.
```

But if any of the ranges have references to entire columns, it will drag the function down to a screeching halt. For instance, these are not okiedokie, and they need to be tested for and avoided:

```
Range("A:A")
Range("A:Z")
Range("AA:ZZ")
```

There are a few ways I've throught of to do this, each of them plausible but with weaknesses. The code contains loops which are used for searching through cells in worksheets with many thousands of rows, so speed is critical.

Here are three ways I can think of, but I'd like to know if there are others..?

1. The simplest & fastest method is to count the rows. If `Range(x).Rows.Count=1048576`, that's the maximum number of rows in a worksheet. However, this wouldn't work if the *actual* number of rows turned out to be exactly that number, or if by some wild chance there were multiple overlapping areas/ranges
   that all added up to that number. Both unlikely, but possible. Also, if the version of Excel changes, so might that number, thus rendering the code broken.
2. Use a RegEx match against the text of Range.Address(False,False) with a pattern such as `([A-Z]{1,3}):([A-Z]{1,3})`. I think this would be a medium on the speed scale.
3. Use VBA loops, `If-Then`, and string functions such as `InStr()` and `Mid()` to pick at the text of `Range.Address(False,False)`. I think this would be the slowest possible way to do it.

Comment: For number 1, instead of hard-coding the number of rows, get `Rows.Count` from `Range.Parent`. Also what do you mean by multiple overlapping rows?

Comment: Ranges. Sorry, I mis-spoke, err...mis-typed. I corrected the typo. What I was attempting to convey is a Range variable can have a lot crammed into it. Specifically, many Area objects. Well...maybe not a lot, I seem to recall in my experimentations a while back that the limit of the string in Range({string}) is 255 characters. But anywho, consider this: `Range("A1:D4, B2:E5")`. Those two ranges overlap. It's true that Excel will fix it and break it up into rectangular Area objects without overlap, but my function will accept anything as input, so the overlap is a possbility.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of Range.Parent.Rows.Count; that works well for getting the maximum rows. Following that lead, I nosed around the Locals in Debug mode and I see that could be found in a couple of different ways.

Answer (score 1):

You could test if the range is a reference to a column by checking the `Range.Address` against the `Range.EntireColumn.Address`  like this:

```
If Range("AA:ZZ").Address = Range("AA:ZZ").EntireColumn.Address Then
    'This returns True
End If

If Range("AA1:ZZ4").Address = Range("AA1:ZZ4").EntireColumn.Address Then
    'This returns False
End If
```

Comment: Interesting. Your mention of .EntireColumn got me thinking, and I realized I have to change the way I approach this. No matter what I do, the way my function works, it will accept any combination of range references. Normally I use `Intersect(UsedRange, Range(SomeRange))` to constrain looping activities, and this might apply to testing for a column as you suggested. But...I'm just going to have to allow for the fact that the function might end up hitting the maximum rows, and either warn the user with a `MsgBox`, or just let it do the work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question completely but this might work for you:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Debug.Print RowCheck(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10"))
End Sub

Public Function RowCheck(InputRange As Range)
    Dim u As Long 'used number of rows
    Dim x As Long 'max number of rows for any column
    Dim r As Long 'number of rows based on input range

    With InputRange
        u = Cells(Rows.Count, .Columns(1).Column).End(xlUp).Row
        r = .Rows.Count
        x = Rows.Count
    End With

    If r = x And u < r Then
        RowCheck = "A bad column reference provided"
    Else
        RowCheck = "This is a valid reference"
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after reading everyone's suggestions, I realized that no matter what I do, any `Range` objects passed to my function might include either an entire column reference *or* any combination of overlapping Range references that *result* in an entire column being selected.

But in translation, that means...all rows in the data, aka the `UsedRange`. It's possible with a large amount of data the `UsedRange` may actually hit the last row at 1048576. And any combination of `Range` references passed to my `Function` *might* result in a huge area that does cover an entire column, all the way to the maximum row.

Of course the likelihood of that happening is very low, but I do like to cover all bases in my code. But the key to this puzzle is `UsedRange`. This creates a "synthetic maximum last row". If the `GrandRange`, for lack of a better name, covers all rows in the `UsedRange`, then my function has nothing to do and no data to return. And so a simple IF-Then-Exit should give me the solution I was looking for:

```
If Intersect(UsedRange,LeGrandeRange).Rows.Count = UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
    'All rows in `UsedRange` are affected.
    'Nothing to do.
    Exit Function
Else
    'Do everything here.
    'Then exit normally.
    ...
    ...
    ...
Endif
```